# offsetof with char as second argument. Is it possible?

Tags: c

I'd love to create some part dynamically. Would it be possible to use `offsetof` with string as a second argument? Something like:

```
offsetof( tic, "close.v");
```

Or can I convert `char` to `member` anyhow?

Comment: Um, read the documentation ... offsetof works nothing like that. And a string literal isn't `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `offsetof` construct is a compile time operation.  It can't be used with anything that is generated dynamically.